# Calling fopen with an output from fgets

Tags: c, fopen, fgets

I am trying to open files with an output from `fgets` from another text file.

Specifically, my "./list.txt" contains all of the relative paths to the files I want to open.

For example, this is what list.txt looks like:

```
./tst/f/ak/1237743.txt
./tst/f/ak/1393387.txt
./tst/f/ak/276317o.txt
./tst/f/ak/44z5938.txt
.
.
.
```

and so on.

What I tried to do was get one line from this "list.txt" and use that output as a parameter for another fopen call, thereby resulting in opening of "./tst/f/ak/1237743.txt" and so on.

I made a very simple code to see whether or not this could be done.

This is how my code looks like:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("./list.txt", "r");
    if(f==NULL){

        printf("failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char tmp[255];
    char *addr;
    addr = fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmp), f);
    addr[strlen(addr)-1] = '\0';
    fclose(f);
    printf("%s\n", addr);

    FILE *x;
    x = fopen(addr, "r");
    if(x==NULL){

        printf("failure\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Success\n");

    fclose(x);
}
```

This is what I got:

> ./tst/f/ak/1237743.txt
>
> failure

Any help on where I'm doing it wrong?

I also tried

```
fopen("./tst/f/ak/1237743.txt", "r)
```

and it worked fine, so I am sure there is nothing wrong with relative paths here...

Comment: You could improve the printing by enclosing the name in, for example, square brackets: `printf("[%s]\n", addr);`  This would show whether there is a newline, or perhaps a carriage return, in the string `addr`.  And that, I suspect, is the cause of your problem.  You'd probably see the `]` on a different line from the `[`.  Alternatively, you might see the `]` at the start of the line and not see the `[` at all. Also, are you compiling and running on a Unix derivative or on Windows?  Was the data file ever on a Windows machine?  (I guess you're using Linux and the data file came from Windows.)

Comment: Wow, you are right. [%s]\n shows "]./tst/f/ak/1237743.txt". And yes, I am using Ubuntu but the list.txt file was created from a Windows machine. Is this the source of the problem?

Comment: That's a carriage return before the newline that you zap.  Your list of file names spent enough time close enough to a Windows machine to be infected with CRLF line endings, but your machine doesn't translate the CRLF line endings to newline when reading a text file.  That's consistent with you running on a Unix-based machine.  So **Yes** — the configuration information you give is the source of your trouble; Windows data on a Unix (Linux, Ubuntu) machine.  The trick of surrounding text strings with marker characters can often diagnose problems like this quite quickly.  It's worth remembering.

Comment: Thank you! So I guess I have to create a whole new list.txt file...

Comment: You have a couple of options.  One would be to create a new file.  You could use a conversion utility such as `dos2unix` to convert the file.  Or you could strip newlines or CRLF by using `addr[strcspn(addr, "\r\n")] = '\0';`.  That will put the null byte at the first CR or LF it encounters, or overwrite the null byte with a null byte if there are no CR or LF characters (so it is safe, even with degenerate data).

Comment: Second one worked perfectly! Thank you so much

Comment: Use `errno` perhaps thru `perror` when `fopen`  (or some other standard function) fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Copying comments into an answer.*</sup>

The basic problem is that your data file has CRLF (DOS-style) line endings but you're working on a Unix machine that doesn't map CRLF to newline, unlike a Windows machine.

> You could improve the printing by enclosing the name in, for example, square brackets:
>
> ```
> printf("[%s]\n", addr);
> ```
>
> This would show whether there is a newline, or perhaps a carriage return, in the string addr. And that, I suspect, is the cause of your problem. You'd probably see the `]` on a different line from the `[`. Alternatively, you might see the `]` at the start of the line and not see the `[` at all.
>
> Also, are you compiling and running on a Unix derivative or on Windows? Was the data file ever on a Windows machine? (I guess you're using Linux and the data file came from Windows.)

To which the response was:

> Wow, you are right. `[%s]\n` shows "`]./tst/f/ak/1237743.txt`". And yes, I am using Ubuntu but the `list.txt` file was created from a Windows machine. Is this the source of the problem?

And the answer is:

> That's a carriage return before the newline that you zap. […] **Yes** — the configuration information you give is the source of your trouble; Windows data on a Unix (Linux, Ubuntu) machine.
>
> The trick of surrounding text strings with marker characters can often diagnose problems like this quite quickly. It's worth remembering.

And again:

> Thank you! So I guess I have to create a whole new `list.txt` file?

To which the response is:

> You have a couple of options.  One would be to create a new file.  You could use a conversion utility such as `dos2unix` to convert the file.  Or you could strip newlines or CRLF by using `strcspn()` instead of `strlen()`, like this:
>
> ```
> addr[strcspn(addr, "\r\n")] = '\0';`
> ```
>
> That will put the null byte at the first CR or LF it encounters, or overwrite the null byte with a null byte if there are no CR or LF characters (so it is safe, even with degenerate data).